# Using original depth/coordinate data, "marmap" package. Trouble plotting bathymetry charts

Tags: r

I'm using the marmap package to make bathymetry charts of small shallow lakes in the Yukon Territory, Canada.

My data is hand sampled, in a CSV file, three columns:

*Longitude, Latitude, Depth*

I simply used the "as.bathy", then "is.bathy" to ensure it is in the correct format and finally used the "plot.bathy" to produced... a blank plot.

This plot shows me latitudes and longitudes but does not illustrate any depths.

I have now realized that these depth values are entirely lacking in 0 values. 
This means that R does not know where the shoreline is and I believe this may be a huge factor in my problems plotting.

Would an appropriate course of action now be to go into QGIS and take shoreline values with 0 depths and coordinates, in order to provide R with a shoreline?

Or should I use a different methodology for producing these charts? 
At this stage, I am trying to compare different methodologies to producing these bathymetry charts, where efficient time and ease of plotting are major concerns.

Thank you.

---

edit-update

---

so I have updated my CSV to include shoreline values, staggered along shoreline with a 0 depth. replotted, and same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem comes from the non-rectangular format of your data. read.bathy() and as.bathy() cannot yet deal with missing data in a bathy file. Adding zeros along the coastline won't help.
The good news is we will be releasing marmap v0.8 in the next few days with an updated version of read.bathy() that will be capable of handling this type of data. After updating to marmap 0.8, you will just need to type the following code:

```
library(marmap)
dat <- read.bathy("my_cvs_file.csv")
plot(dat)
```

In the meantime, you can just:

1. load marmap 0.7
2. copy/paste the code below in the R console
3. use the function read.bathy2() instead of read.bathy() in your script.

The code provided below just add NAs in the bathy matrix where it is appropriate (i.e. where you don't have any data).

I hope this helps!

```
add.nas <- function(vec,pos.missing) {

    vec.new <- NULL
    n.mis <- length(pos.missing)

    for (i in 1:n.mis) {
        modify.vec <- TRUE
        range <- 1:(pos.missing[i]-1)

        if (identical(range,1:0)) {
            range <- 0
            modify.vec <- FALSE
        }

        vec.new <- c(vec.new,vec[range],NA)
        if (modify.vec) vec <- vec[-range]
        pos.missing <- pos.missing - pos.missing[i]
    }

    vec.new <- c(vec.new,vec)
    return(vec.new)
}

read.bathy2 <- function (xyz, header = FALSE, sep = ",") {

    bath <- read.table(xyz, header = header, sep = sep)
    bath <- bath[order(bath[, 2], bath[, 1], decreasing = FALSE), ]

    lat <- unique(bath[, 2]) ; bcol <- length(lat)
    lon <- unique(bath[, 1]) ; brow <- length(lon)

    if ((bcol*brow) == nrow(bath)) {
        mat <- matrix(bath[, 3], nrow = brow, ncol = bcol, byrow = FALSE, dimnames = list(lon, lat))
        } else {
            id <- apply(bath[,-3],1,function(x) c(which(lon==x[1]) , which(lat==x[2])) )
            pos.missing <- which(table(id[1,],id[2,])==0)
            mat <- matrix(add.nas(bath[,3],pos.missing), nrow = brow, ncol = bcol, byrow = FALSE, dimnames = list(lon, lat))
        }

    ordered.mat <- check.bathy(mat)
    class(ordered.mat) <- "bathy"
    return(ordered.mat)
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll give it a shot when it comes out.

Answer (score 0):

marmap 0.8 will be available on cran soon, but you can already install the new version via github:

```
install.packages("devtools")
library(devtools)
install_github("marmap","ericpante")
```

The function `read.bathy` has been modified to deal with non rectangular bathymetry files.

Comment: I'm getting a strange error message, not exactly sure why:

Error in texi2dvi(file = file, pdf = TRUE, clean = clean, quiet = quiet,  : 
  pdflatex is not available
Calls: <Anonymous> -> texi2pdf -> texi2dvi
Execution halted
Error: Command failed (1)

Comment: Are you using a Mac? If yes, the problem is due to the inability of the system to find the path to your Latex tree. Just run the following command before the `install_github` code: `Sys.setenv(PATH=paste(Sys.getenv("PATH"),"/usr/texbin",sep=":"))
`

Comment: seems to me that the error is:
*creating vignettes ... ERROR

then it repeats the error given above.

Comment: Yes. If the system can't find the path to the Latex distribution, then the vignette cannot be compiled. Another possible problem might be due to the `shape` package that is needed for the vignette to compile but that was not included in the `Imports` section of the Description file of the marmap package. This is now corrected and everything should compile nicely. Finally, if everything else fails, you can just compile the package without the vignette by calling `install_github("marmap", "ericpante", build_vignettes=FALSE)`